# How could I execut this code in python (awk example provided) file seperator

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I would like to exectute the following awk code as python code what would be the best way forward? If I was to use a list how would I popluate the list such that in the end I could print out fields 1 and 3 back to an output list and write this to a file.

thanks
graham

```
AWK 

#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
        FS=":";
}
{
                print $1,$3
        }
```

test file

```
Error code 27: This is error code 27:Ihave no comment here
Error code 24: This is error code 27:Ihave no comment here
Error code 27: This is error code 27:Ihave no comment here
Error code 26: This is error code 27:Ihave no comment here
Error code 27: This is error code 27:Ihave no comment here
Error code 29: This is error code 27:Ihave no comment here
Error code 01: This is error code 27:Ihave no comment here
```

Comment: I don't really speak AWK, and I suspect there are many python programmer out there who does neither. So you'd better include the expected output for the input file, from that, one can figure out the python solution without looking at the AWK code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f = open(file_name)
for line in f:
  s = line.split(':')
  print s[0],s[2]
```

Comment: Thanks G.Z I understand now graham